# Laravel 5.5 shouldn't be able to authenticate user

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I try to authenticate using a custom table from database.

Table name is kullanicilar and the fields I use for the authentication are eposta and sifre respectively.

My session controller class is like this:

```
class OturumDenetcisi extends Controller
{
    public function kaydet(Request $request)
    {

        if (!\Auth::attempt(['eposta' => $request->eposta, 'password' => $request->sifre]))
        {
            return back();
        }

        return redirect()->home();
    }
    // ...
}
```

Also in user model I have

```
# In user model

public function getAuthPassword () 
{

    return $this->sifre;

}
```

When I try to authenticate user nothing happens. It takes me back.

Here is the `dd ($request->all());` output inside kaydet function which tries to store a new session.

```
 array:3 [▼
   "_token" => "KfbftPRMVkm4bBIWo8WoICOHmaDyvRpDhF8Wk4zq"
   "eposta" => "elma@elma.com"
   "sifre" => "a123"
 ]
```

**UPDATE :** [SOLVED]

After saving the passwords to database using hashing methods now it works as excepted. Here is the complete session controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Kullanici;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

class OturumDenetcisi extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'cikisYap']);
    }

    public function olustur()
    {
        return view('oturumlar.olustur');
    }

    public function kaydet(Request $request)
    {

        if (!\Auth::attempt(['eposta' => $request->eposta, 'password' => $request->sifre]))
        {
            return back();
        }

        return redirect()->home();
    }

    public function cikisYap()
    {
        auth()->logout();
        return redirect('/');
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you stored the password on the table? Is that a hashed value?

Comment: No it is stored as normal text.

Comment: The attempt() method will hash the password you given in the array and then compare it with the password value from the database.

Comment: Sidenote; don't store passwords in your database in plain text. Since you're using Laravel, you have access to `Hash::` functions, so passwords should at the very least be stored as `$model->password = \Hash::make("password");` There are also packages available for Laravel which handles the Auth stuff automatically; consider researching that too.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to make sure you are using the proper username column to search for credentials:

```
<?php

namespace App\Data\Entities;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * Get the login username to be used by the controller.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function username()
    {
        return 'eposta';
    }
}
```

Then you also have to check if your user is being found with the credentials you are sending to Laravel, so this is a way to test it:

```
public function kaydet(Request $request)
{
    $user = User::where('eposta', $request->eposta)->first();
    dump($user); // does it find the user?

    dd(Hash::check($request->sifre, $user->password)); // is the password right?

    if (!\Auth::attempt(['eposta' => $request->eposta, 'password' => $request->sifre]))
    {
        return back();
    }

    return redirect()->home();
}
```

Comment: It finds the user but the output of the second dd function is false.

Comment: Looks like your passwords are not matching. You have to check the password hash